# Why null values are allowed inside java List

Tags: java, list

If I am writing

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
list1.add(null);
list1.add(null);
```

Java allows that . Why ??
Any use of list1[0] will any way result into NPE .

Comment: Try list1.get(0) it won't give NPE

Comment: list1[0] won't even compile, so this question doesn't make much sense just because of that. Also, as others have noted, correct syntax for lists (list1.get(0)) will NOT throw a NPE on null values, but will simply return null. Please do at least a minimal research before posting a question...

Comment: Can you imagine if `list.add()` threw an exception every time a null value was inserted?? Oh wait, `List.of(...)` does that. SMH

Comment: @JoshM. Yup, just got bitten by this on what I thought was a minor non-breaking refactor, making use of List.of(). Oh Java, you are disappointing with your inconsistencies..

Answer (score 19):

> Java allows that. Why?

Because the `List` is a collection of object references. Since `null` is a *valid* reference (for all types), then the compiler allows statements like `list1.add(null)`

Answer (score 6):

First in place you can't access a `list` element like  `list1[0]`, that syntax is to access from `array`. If you want to access from list, you need to write `list.get(0)`;

Coming to your actual question, it won't give you NPE and list allows you to add `null`'s to it. When you try to return, It returns `null` only.

If you try to invoke methods/variables on that resulted `null`, then you run into NPE.

Answer (score 6):

> Any use of list1[0] will any way result into NPE .

No it won't:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
list1.add(null);
String foo = list1.get(0);    // No NPE here
if (foo == someOtherObject) { // Nor here
    // Do something
}
```

`List` maintains a list of object references. Object references can either be a reference to a valid, extant object, or `null` to indicate that they don't currently contain an object reference.

*Semantically*, a `List` containing a `null` entry is *different* from a `List` that doesn't have an entry in that position *at all*. Not having an entry *at all* can easily have a different meaning from having an entry with `null` or having a non-`null` entry at a given position.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on `List` implementation. The interface as such, does not enforce whether `null` values should be allowed or not.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) :

> Unlike sets, lists typically allow duplicate elements. More formally,
>   lists typically allow pairs of elements e1 and e2 such that
>   e1.equals(e2), and they typically allow multiple null elements if they
>   allow null elements at all.

Again :

> Some list implementations have restrictions on the elements that they
>   may contain. For example, some implementations prohibit null elements,
>   and some have restrictions on the types of their elements. Attempting
>   to add an ineligible element throws an unchecked exception, typically
>   NullPointerException or ClassCastException.

Answer (score 1):

[`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) permits `null` elements,

> Implements all optional list operations, and permits all elements, including null.

but not necessarily other implementations.

For example, Java9 [`List.of()` does not permit `null` elements.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable):

> They disallow null elements. Attempts to create them with null elements result in NullPointerException.

See also [`Collection` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#optional-restrictions):

> Some collection implementations have restrictions on the elements that they may contain. For example, some implementations prohibit null elements, and some have restrictions on the types of their elements. Attempting to add an ineligible element throws an unchecked exception, typically NullPointerException or ClassCastException.

Comment: "They disallow null elements. Attempts to create them with null elements result in NullPointerException." Sorry everyone but this is so, so dumb.